# radio button "checked" disappearing after click to another radio button

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have two radio buttons, one of them is "checked" (according to server response - 0 or 10), and I need to click one of the buttons to send new data to the server (ether value 0 or 10). I have working code, data is sending to the server correctly, all is working. But the problem is - property "checked" is disappearing from both buttons after clicking one of them...

Can some one help me?

```
this.state = {          
   status: ""          
}


statusHandler(e) {
  this.setState({ status: e.target.value });
}

<div className="modal-body">
  <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input className="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="inlineRadioOptions"
      id="inlineRadio1"
      value={0}
      checked={this.state.status === 0 ? true : false}
      onChange={(e) => this.statusHandler(e)} />
    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio1">Open</label>
  </div>
  <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input className="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="inlineRadioOptions"
      id="inlineRadio2"
      value={10}
      checked={this.state.status === 10 ? true : false}
      onChange={(e) => this.statusHandler(e)} />
    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio2">Done</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `e.target.value` is giving you ['String'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) value and you are checking condition with [`===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons). So you need to convert you value into [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or you can check condition with `==`.

You can convert you [string to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer) using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or `+e.target.value`.

Please see below code snippet and working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-checked-disappearing-after-click-to-another-radio) demo.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      status: ''
    };
  }
  statusHandler(e) {
    this.setState({ status: +e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal-body">
        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input className="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="inlineRadioOptions"
            id="inlineRadio1"
            value={0}
            checked={this.state.status === 0 ? true : false}
            onChange={(e) => this.statusHandler(e)} />
          <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio1">Open</label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input className="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="inlineRadioOptions"
            id="inlineRadio2"
            value={10}
            checked={this.state.status === 10 ? true : false}
            onChange={(e) => this.statusHandler(e)} />
          <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio2">Done</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works! that was a stupid mistake of mine)